# Broken image on mouseup when MVC ActionResult called for file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I originally created a button that changed the src based on mouseup and mousedown to give it the appearance of being depressed when clicked as well as playing a click sound.  This worked out fine until I tried to force PDF download through MVC action.  I've tried to skin this cat a few different ways but I've settled on using the mouseup function to set the window location to my pdf download action passing in the needed file download path information.  Now when I click the button it depresses (correctly executing mousedown), then on mouseup it correctly plays the click sound and also downloads the pdf file as I want, but makes the button image appear to be broken.

When I first load the page and the button hasn't been clicked yet the image looks like it's supposed to.  Then after running mouseup it's broken (using Chrome or disappears or appears garbled in IE and Safari) but when I inspect the source the src attribute looks to be identical so I'm not sure why it's returning a broken image if the src is the same as it was before.

Code-

View jquery:

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];

    $('#MAAX-DGB-Button').mouseup(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '../../Content/Images/AdLandingViews/MAAX-DGB.png');
        audio.play();

        var pdfDownload = '/Locator/ForcePDFDownload?PDFURL=<file location info>';
        window.location = pdfDownload;
    });
    $('#MAAX-DGB-Button').mousedown(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '../../Content/Images/AdLandingViews/MAAX-DGB_press.png');
    });
```

View HTML:

```
<img src="../../Content/Images/AdLandingViews/MAAX-DGB.png" alt="Download MAAX Collection Brochure" id="MAAX-DGB-Button" />
```

ForcePDFDownload MVC Action:

```
public ActionResult ForcePDFDownload(string PDFURL)
    {
        string path = @"\\<server location>\" + PDFURL;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(PDFURL);
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        return File(path, "application/pdf");
    }
```

You can test the code here:
https://maaxspasportal.com/Locator/AdLandingLocate/MAAXCollection but you'll have to fill in some dummy data and submit the form to get to the results page where this issue is occurring on the "Download Green Brochure" button.

Tested Browsers:

Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 - Image appears broken.

IE 10 - Image disappears or looks garbled.

Safari 6.0.5 - Image disappears.

FireFox 22.0 - Works!

Thanks for any help getting this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I never determined the exact root cause for the issues, however I did find a way to fix the problem.

On mouseup I applied a setTimeout delay on the forced pdf download function:

```
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];

    $('#MAAX-DGB-Button').mouseup(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '../../Content/Images/AdLandingViews/MAAX-DGB.png');
        audio.play();

        var pdfDownload = '/Locator/ForcePDFDownload?PDFURL=assets.maaxspas.com/docsources/1/138ee0a8-e0f0-47d5-9447-fca6f538d74f.pdf';
        setTimeout(function() { window.location = pdfDownload }, 1000);
    });
    $('#MAAX-DGB-Button').mousedown(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '../../Content/Images/AdLandingViews/MAAX-DGB_press.png');
    });
```

Would still be interested to know what was going wrong but at least it's functioning the way I want now.

Thanks.